# How can I use a value from one column to populate a nan in another column and viceversa in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

There are 2 columns in my Pandas dataframe.

```
cola    colb  
X         X     
C        NaN    
NaN       R     
X         X
```

I want to get rid of cola and colb and replace it with colc.

```
cola    colb   colc
X         X     X
C        NaN    C
NaN       R     R
X         X     X
```

Basically I need to populate colc with the value in cola and colb. If there is a nan in cola then it will pull from colb and if there is a nan in colb it will pull from cola. cola and colb should always be equal if it doesn't have a nan in one of them.

How would I achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df["colc"] = df["cola"].fillna(df["colb"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `np.where` to create logical conditions to fill your array:

```
df["colc"] = np.where(df["cola"].notna(),df["cola"],df["colb"])
```